# I am trying to sort my collection when I add a new object to it, but it is not sorting and there are no errors

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

in my Backbone view, a user can add a new educational research opportunity by hitting a button.

Each research opportunity has a sequence in the database and this is how it's ordered on my page.

When I add it, it writes to the database fine and the sequence is correct, but it doesn't sort it until after I hit refresh/reload page in the browser.

I am asking it to sort but it still doesn't work.

Here is the function in my view:

```
addResearchOpp: function () {
    var self = this;
    this.educationalOpp.research().then((r) => {
        self.model.collection.add(r);
        self.collection.sort({ silent: true });
    });
},
```

Is there anything else I need to do ?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `self` here, and `this.model.collection` is weird. It looks like you are not sorting what you are adding. I would suggest just.

```
this.collection.add(r)
```

Also the `{silent:true}` explains why you need to refresh. Except if you have a very strong reason, like batching and improving performances, I would not use `{silent:true}`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Nicolas Zozol wrote, you may need to set the [`comparator`](https://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) of your collection. If `sequence` is the actual name of the field by which the models are ordered, it would look like this:

```js
var ResearchOpportunities = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // ...
    comparator: 'sequence',
    // ...
});
```